# Jquery-Mobile data Icons not displaying when using iis 8

Tags: visual-studio, jquery-mobile, iis

I am using jquery-mobile version 1.2.0.   When I run it in my development environment everything works great.   when I publish it to windows server 2012/IIS 8

I don't see the Icons for the jquery-mobile ui features....things like arrow-r, home, back etc... the buttons show up, but the icons are empty.

I have checked to make sure the png files are being pushed to the iis and they are.

Both my local and iis have the icons in ~/Content/Themes/base/images  where the jquery-mobile controls are in ~/Content/Themes/Base

Any ideas?

Comment: How are u referring to the icons in jqm's css file?

Comment: check it through fiddler whether images are getting loaded to browser or it is an issue of browser is not been able to display it. In some IE `CMYK` type .jpg images are not visible but are loaded correctly.

Comment: I am not referring to the icons directly .... this may be part of what is confusing me....using jquery-mobile I do the following:

Comment: opps... continue of previous comment.               <div data-role="header"> 
              <a onclick="history.back(); return false;" data-icon="back" >Back</a>     
               <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
               <a href="~/Home/Index" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </div>

Comment: using data-icon to refer to the various icons ... but you never specify the location ...as I understand it jquery-mobile ASSUMES a location for an image folder in the same directory as the controls....which is what I have.....Have tried fiddler and did not see anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem....When I was added the jquery framework it create the images folder in the correct location on my dev machine ...the right folder being ~/Content/Mobile/Css/Images

However, I had neglected to include this folder in my project.  When looking for the images used by the data-icons I found them in another folder ~content/images.....  I think months ago I had put these here to try to get the data-icon images to work on the local dev machine.... and had forget about them...

Any way having the folder present on the local machine let the icon images be displayed....but not having the folder copy over to IIS caused them not to be displayed...